# Meaning and position of mal

Tags: modal-particle

A recent Slow German Podcast begins with the sentence,

> Es wird Zeit, dass ich Euch mal wieder etwas aus dem deutschen Fernsehen empfehle.

My question is regarding the word "mal". I believe it is being used as a modal particle to softening the meaning of the sentence. However, I am curious about its position. I would think the softening would be with regard to the recommendation and therefore the mal should be positioned just before the "empfehle". Why is it in this position?

Comment: Replace it with _einmal_ to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mal wieder** and **wieder mal** are fixed combinations. The meaning is the same: this is another *infrequent* installment.

Let's compare *mal*, *wieder*, and *mal wieder/wieder mal*:

> Es gibt heute mal keinen Kaffee.

"No coffee today, but I made the best out of this situation." This is an excuse. The reason is *mal* means *einmal*, and tomorrow there will be coffee again.

> Es gibt wieder keinen Kaffee.

Next day, someone is annoyed there is no coffee. Again.

> Es gibt wieder mal keinen Kaffee.
>
> Es gibt mal wieder keinen Kaffee.

No coffee today. Again. Shit happens. At least it's not every day.